# Noise in mm-wave initial access frameworks

Tags: noise, communication, wireless, telecommunications, 5g

I have a doubt about Initial Access (IA) procedures in mm-wave system.

In most papers I have read (see e.g. [Initial Access in 5G mm-Wave Cellular Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07731.pdf)), most of the alignment procedures assume that an exhaustive search (or some iterative hierarchical search) is enough to identify the optimal beam (e.g. the one achieving the highest SINR or throughput) between Transmitter and receiver.

[image]

None of the papers I read consider noisy observations, so that one would need for example to sample the beam multiple times in order to determine which one is the best.

Is there a particular reason why the noise in the measurements is not considered in these problems? Is it because it is negligible?

I could not find the answer anywhere. Any hint or reference that study this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have not thoroughly read the paper.  But in the abstract, it says "...We show that the best strategy depends on the target SNR regime...".  That implies to me that their analysis included the effects of noise.

Comment: And Table II Simulation Parameters mentions a min SNR threshold of - 5 dB.